# edit a php file array variable from another

Tags: php, text-files

i am trying to create some switches saved in other files, already tried to make it turn a text file into array but it didnt worked well since itdoesnt seem to even read the file properly and dont get anything from inside of it. now i got the idea of having php files that have the arrays and it can be changed by a main php file
this will be the entire switch file:

```
<?php
    function getarray(){
        $a = array(
            'name_on' => 0,
            'picture_on' = 0,
            'custom_styling_on' = 0
        );
        return $a;
    }
?>
```

and i would like to edit the values of the array from the main file, but i dont know exactly how.
but if someone know how to create an array from a text file it will work, but just remember i tried what the answer of other questions said to and didnt worked

Comment: Reading data from a text file is generally straightforward, but of course what you can do with it depends a bit on the format of the data stored in the file. What exactly did you store in your text file? What code did you use to try and extract it and turn it into an array? What exactly went wrong. Telling us you tried some things from other answers and that they didn't work gives us no insight at all into your specific problem, and so there is no way to help us resolve it. Hint: it's quite easy to read JSON from text files, and JSON is very good for storing array data, among other things.

Comment: `<?php
function reading(){
    $fp = fopen('toggles.txt', 'r'); 
    $toggles = explode(PHP_EOL, $fp);
    return array($toggles,$fp);
}
function getvalues(){
    list($toggles,$fp) = reading();
    list($name_on,$unnecesary_thing,$a,$b) = $toggles;
    return array($name_on,$toggles,$fp);
    }
?>` this is my code i made to read the file
the txt file was :
`0`
`ba`
but i just got `key:0 value:`
and nothing else, i was expecting to be: `key:0` `value:0`,`key:1` `value:ba`

Comment: i will try the json tho

Comment: Next time if you have code and data to show us, please add it to your question - as you can see it's barely readable like that. Use the "edit" button under your question - thanks :-)

Comment: ok i will, thank you too

Answer (score 1):

as [ADyson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037099/edit-a-php-file-array-variable-from-another?noredirect=1#comment120253392_68037099)

a json for an array will be way more useful, i have changed my code to,so if i press a button it will change the value:

```
<?php
function getvalues(){
    $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."\switch.json");
    $arr = json_decode($json,true);
    return $arr;
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    setval('name',0);
}
function setval($key,$value){
    $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."\switch.json");
    $arr = json_decode($json,true);
    $arr[$key] = $value;
    $jarr = json_encode($arr);
    file_put_contents("switch.json",$jarr);
}
?>
```